Emacs Command Not Found After Installing In MobaXTerm
I'm having trouble installing emacs in MobaXTerm. When I open a new terminal I'm in the path home/mobaxterm. When typing emacs example.cpp in the terminal, I get an error emacs: command not found and emacs can be installed using the following command: apt install emacs.
But when I do type apt install emacs it says that Package emacs is already installed. I figured this must be because the emacs command is not in usr/bin/. To check if it is I went into the directory bin and listed the contents with ls, but could not find emacs.exe file, as if emacs was never installed. Not sure what is happening here. Was wondering if someone can help me with why I'm not able to use emacs even though it is installed.

To me, it sounds as if your PATH is not set correctly, but I know nothing about MobaXTerm.
